# Edit and Delete doesn't work for Angular Leaflet

Tags: angular, leaflet, leaflet.draw, ngx-leaflet, leaflet-draw

I am trying to edit and delete the shapes that I draw on the leaflet map. However, when I active the edit or draw, nothing happens and I am unable to edit the shape. I am currently importing leaflet and leaflet-draw into my application:

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-draw';
```

And this is how my code looks like:

```
edit() {
    let edit = new L.EditToolbar.Edit(map, {
        featureGroup: featureGroupOptions,
        selectedPathOptions: {},
    } as any);
}

delete() {
    let delete= new L.EditToolbar.Delete(map, {
        featureGroup: featureGroupOptions
    } as any);
}
```

The map shows that I can edit or delete the polygon but I can't actually drag the vertexes nor delete the polygon. Am I doing something wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can try a different drawing tool. Leaflet-draw is not maintained anymore and has many bugs. For example you can use [Leaflet-Geoman](https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman)

Comment: Leaflet-draw works fine for me on Javascript though, it just doesn't seem to work when I migrate it to Angular? Also with Leaflet-Geoman, can I use ngx-leaflet with it + have my own custom toolbar and use the edit and delete function?